# How to get product collection in magento 2

Tags: magento2, api, product-collection

I am trying to create an API in magento 2 to get all product information. I have prepared a simple API module and it is working fine. Now I am trying to fetch product collection, but getting an error.

Here is my Code:

```
<?php 

namespace CompanyName\Connector\Model;

    use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
    use CompanyName\Connector\Api\OdooInterface;
    use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory as ProductCollectionFactory;

    class Odoo implements OdooInterface
    {
        protected $productCollectionFactory;

        public function __construct(ProductCollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory)
        {
            $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        }

        /**
         * Returns Product collection
         *
         * @api
         *
         * @return $collection
         */
        public function getProductCollection()
        {
            $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
            $collection->setPageSize(3); // fetching only 3 products
            return $collection;
        }
    }
```

Here is the error I am getting:

> Fatal Error: 'Call to undefined method Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection\Interceptor::getProductCollection()' in '/var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/DataObjectProcessor.php' on line 86

Please let me know, if any one have solution for it.

Answer (score 2):

**OPTION 1:**

You can use repositories for this and return a `SearchResultsInterface`.

**OPTION 2:**

Use Magento API `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface` witha search filter.

**OPTION 3:**

Change your code to return an array of ProductInterface

```
...
    /**
     * Returns Product collection
     *
     * @api
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface[]
     */
    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->setPageSize(3); // fetching only 3 products

        $res = [];
        foreach ($collection as $product) {
           $res[] = $product;
        }

        return $res;
    }
...
```

**WARNING:** Rememeber to set `@return  \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface[]` on your interface or it will not work